# Name of this font used in Porsche 918 Ad?

Tags: font-identification

What is the font used in **[this ad](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dDJ7-P7WIxI)**?

[image: Screenshot of the font]

ADD other symbols

[image]

Comment: Hi there! Have you tried cleaning the image and using http://www.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont ? You might want to check out this meta post: http://meta.graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/1083/guidelines-for-font-identification-questions There are some other suggestions on how to better identify fonts. I recommend you try to find a better sample, maybe do a search for similar (graphic) ads.

Comment: Yes, uploaded in Myfonts tool and whatthefont forum.
No help yet.

Comment: Do you try to recognise the font of "On my way"? On of the word "Input"?

Comment: A better screenshot (and not having to view the video) would greatly assist here.

Comment: [Here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/TXg4D.png) is a slightly higher-res shot.

Comment: Tons of imagery: http://www.automobilemag.com/features/news/1406-s1nn-explains-the-porsche-918-spyder-infotainment-system/photo_06.html . HTML5/webkit interface for embedded systems developed by s1nn

Answer (score 1):

Looks like Yanone Kaffeesatz  [Preview this Google Font on Typcast](http://typecast.com/preview/google/Yanone%20Kaffeesatz)

[image]

Comment: Little close but Yanone Kaffeesatz much curvy

Answer (score 0):

It looks a bit like cachet. The YMCA re-branded recently and uses this font.

Edit; More information on Cachet here;

http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/mti/cachet/webfont_preview.html

Example of campaign use here;

http://ymca.org/

Comment: Welcome to GD.  Do you mind posting an example of the font you are suggesting and where you would find said font to assist the OP?

Answer (score 0):

Check out Klint from Linotype:

http://www.linotype.com/de/619527/Klint-family.html

[image]

(source image is a perspective corrected photo from the link in my comment to the question, so there is some skew and noise etc)

FYI, I composited a few lines from that corrected photo and offered it to the myfonts imagery tool.

Comment: 4 in Klint is closed, and on the video it is open

Comment: In the photos in article I linked in the comments above, the "4' is closed. I looked again at the video and I see no "4" at all in the interface. Can you provide a video time stamp of a specimen?

Comment: on the photos you provided the font is apparently different

Comment: It looks identical to me

Comment: Please, check out letter "e" - on the pictures from ads the lower horizontal part is shorter than the upper loop, while in the font you placed the lower part of the e is longer and reaches the right border of the letter

Comment: the same is right for "a" letter

Comment: I only quickly corrected the perspective of the image. The detail differences that you refer to are caused by the obvious warp and skew of the image, not to mention the choice of AA and the difference in rendering engine.

Comment: I am afraid, I cannot agree with you today :) On the image I placed on question it is clear the perspective plays no roles in "a" and "e"  - you can see that on the video clearly. :)